# Why shouldn't my ViewModel depends on concrete implementation of services?

Tags: unit-testing, mvvm, dependency-injection, mocking

My ViewModel usually have a  dependency to some services through interfaces *(DI containers will inject the actual implementations*). So that I could create a mock behavior of those services for UnitTests.

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
        public MyViewModel(IMyService myService)
        {
        }
}
```

But we have some mocking framework exists like [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart), where you can setup mock behavior for your concrete implementations of services even without interfaces. **Does that mean, the ViewModels can have a dependency with concrete service classes instead of interfaces?** Is there any other purpose for having interfaces apart from UnitTests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But we have some mocking framework exists like Moq, where you can setup mock behavior for your concrete implementations of services even without interfaces

Not exactly. With Moq you can only mock something that can be overriden/implemented. In most cases this would be an interface but sometimes a class with virtual/abstract methods.

Now, if your services expose methods as virtual (question is, *why* would they do that?) then sure, you can use Moq and be able to mock them. Otherwise not.

The point of passing interfaces is to rely on abstraction rather than concrete implementation. This is **D** of [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles - [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

Comment: Actually, no, it's not. DIP is about avoiding a compile-time dependency from a high-level component to a lower-level component on which it depends at runtime, by depending only on an abstraction defined at the high level and implemented at the low level; it does not require DI, nor DI imply that DIP is followed.

Comment: @Rogério: yes, that's what I wrote dressed in more words. What's your point with bringing up DI?

Comment: My point is that the question is about DI, not about DIP. And DI != DIP.

Comment: @Rogério: and where did I write that "DI == DIP"?

Comment: You *implied* it by talking about DIP when the question only mentioned DI.

Answer (score 1):

the general idea is to have a project that can easily evolve. interface gives you a bit less coupling because you can have different implementations, including test implementation (mock). that's the theory.

from my experience: if you have only one service implementation and you can easily mock it then it's sufficient to have only implementation without the interface. if, in future, you need another implementation, you can refactor. but still it requires two things.

- defined interface: still you need a clear definition of the contract your service provides. so you need some methods to public, some other to be private. and your view can't use private methods or it will be much more difficult to do any changes
- devs must understand the interface. if you have explicitly defined interface then it's a good documentation. if you don't have it, it's easier for your team to change it in a way it starts to use features that were supposed to be internal service implementation